# How to fix "No Etag header found" error?

Tags: seo, htaccess, mobile, optimization

I tested my website on [ready.mobi](http://ready.mobi/) and it shows

> MAJOR FAIL
>
> All page assets should use appropriate Etag headers to
>   enable client-side caching and speed up future page loads
>
> ```
> No Etag header found.
> ```

[FixIt page](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/fixit-etag-support) doesn't give me anything helpful - what can I do to solve that problem? .htaccess?

ps. My website runs on some external virtual server with Apache, it's using CodeIgniter PHP framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you can use the header function to specify a custom Etag as follows:

```
 $et="11111"; // any custom etag value
 header("ETag: \"".$et."\"",true);
```

Just make sure when you update the webpage in question that the etag value is updated. If you don't want to do a manual etag update, you can use this code instead:

```
 $et=md5(time()); // 32-bit etag value calculated based on current time in seconds since year 1970.
 header("ETag: \"".$et."\"",true);
```

Since you're using a framework, look in the PHP source for other header() functions and place any of the above code in with that.

Comment: I don't see the point of basing an ETag on the current time (in seconds)? And then why hash it; it will only take up more space (32 chars, not "32-bit")?

Comment: Well, if one makes frequent updates to the site, it would be more convenient to have the Etag be given a value representing time, that way it will be 100% unique every time, thereby causing no internal confusion to the web browser. and yes it takes up 32 chars but it adds small security.

Answer (score 1):

> All **page assets** should use appropriate Etag headers
>
> My website runs on some external virtual server with **Apache**

You can't realistically send `ETag` headers for your *page assets* (ie. static resources: images, scripts, css) using PHP as it would involve sending all the requests for these, otherwise static, resources through PHP which is only going to make everything a lot slower and processor intensive which is defeating the object of setting `ETag`s in the first place.

Fortunately, Apache has `ETag` capability for static files built in. It is enabled by default in Apache, but hosts tend to disable this feature. It can be enabled/overridden in .htaccess using the `FileETag` directive, providing your host has permitted you to do so with the `AccessOverride FileInfo` directive in the server config.

In .htaccess (or server config):

```
# Set ETags based on the files i-node, last modified time and file size (default)
FileETag INode MTime Size
```

Note that if you have load balancing across multiple servers you may want to remove the `INode` keyword, as this will vary from server to server, so would otherwise result in different `ETag`s being sent when the file has not actually changed.

This should be enough to actually set the `ETag` header. However, you need to also make sure that you aren't blocking caching by sending a `Cache-Control: no-store` header (or similar) as the browser then won't send the corresponding `If-None-Match` header with the ETag value previously sent in the response. Both are required. ETag validation should be used in conjunction with regular browser caching.

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#fileetag